# lightGallery.js video gallery not working

Tags: javascript, html, lightgallery

I am trying to include a video gallery of youtube videos using lightgallery but I can't get the video player to work. It instead opens youtube on a new tab. I am using cdn links to load lightgallery and it looks like i'm missing lg-video. However when I include lg-video's cdn link, I am getting console errors about something being undefined. Can someone please answer this with all the script tags that I would need to include in my HTML code?

This is what I have:

```js
lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'), {
    pager:true,
    thumbnail:true,
}); 

lightGallery(document.getElementById('video-gallery'), {});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #152836
}
.demo-gallery > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a > img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover > img {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster > img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a .demo-gallery-poster {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a .demo-gallery-poster > img {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.demo-gallery > ul > li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a > img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover > img {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover .demo-gallery-poster > img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a .demo-gallery-poster {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a .demo-gallery-poster > img {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.demo-gallery .justified-gallery > a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.demo-gallery .video .demo-gallery-poster img {
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 48px;
}
.demo-gallery.dark > ul > li a {
    border: 3px solid #04070a;
}
.home .demo-gallery {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-gallery">

<ul id="video-gallery">
<li class="video" data-src="https://youtu.be/YD_gvR234qg" data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/videos/y-video1-cover.jpg">
    <a href="https://youtu.be/YD_gvR234qg">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-y-1.jpg">
    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
        <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/play-button.png">
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="video" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq9yPrLWMyU"
data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/videos/y-video2-cover.jpg">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq9yPrLWMyU">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-y-2.jpg">
    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
        <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/play-button.png">
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="video" data-src="https://vimeo.com/1084537"
data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/videos/v-video1-cover.jpg">
    <a href="https://vimeo.com/1084537">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-v-1.jpg">
    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
        <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/play-button.png">
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="video" data-src="https://vimeo.com/35451452"
data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/videos/v-video2-cover.jpg">
    <a href="https://vimeo.com/35451452">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-v-2.jpg">
    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
        <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/play-button.png">
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-pager.js/master/dist/lg-pager.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-autoplay.js/master/dist/lg-autoplay.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-fullscreen.js/master/dist/lg-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-zoom.js/master/dist/lg-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-hash.js/master/dist/lg-hash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-share.js/master/dist/lg-share.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-video/1.2.2/lg-video.min.js"></script>
```